# use of Application State Variables and Application Level Events

Tags: c#, asp.net

When talking about state variables, I know the use of View State variables and Session State Variables. View state variables when we need to preserve data accross page postback. Session State variables are used to store username, role of the user, values we need to access throughout a session.

But what is the importance of Application State Variables in real time projects ? What type of values should be stored in these variables ?

What is mean by Application Level Events, what is the real time use of these events? 
Mostly we use Application State Variables in Application Level Events in `Global.asax` file.

Please can you share how and where can we use these variables. How have you utilized the application state variables in your projects?

Answer (score 0):

I've used application state variables as a sort of rudimentary cache on very small production apps that do not do much. But outside of that, I have not found much use for them. E.g. it's pretty straight forward implementing a caching framework; also these variables become quite useless when working in a server farm.

Application level events are basically those events that exist in your global asax like `Application_Start`, `Application_BeginRequest`, `Application_Error` etc. Even then I don't use application state variables in these events - there is always something better to use, like configuration files.

Lastly, to keep your code clean its better to encapsulate these variables in some sort of class (preferably an abstract class that is swapped out using DI) so I see little benefit of using them outside of quick-and-dirty projects.

Comment: Thanks for the response.